# Faster Scraping of JSON from API: Asynchronous or?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to scrape roughly 30GB of JSON data from a website API as quickly as possible. I don't need to parse it -- I just need to save everything that shows up on each API URL.

- I can request quite a bit of data at a time -- say 1MB or even 50MB 'chunks' (API parameters are encoded in the URL and allow me to select how much data I want per request)
- the API  places a limit of 1 request per second.
- I would like to accomplish this on a laptop and 100MB/sec internet connection

Currently, I am accomplishing this (synchronously & too slowly) by:
-pre-computing all of the (encoded) URL's I want to scrape
-using Python 3's requests library to request each URL and save the resulting JSON one-by-one in separate .txt files.

Basically, my synchronous, too-slow solution looks like this (simplified slightly):

```
#for each pre-computed encoded URL do:
    curr_url_request = requests.get(encoded_URL_i, timeout=timeout_secs)
    if curr_url_request.ok:
        with open('json_output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(curr_url_request.json(), outfile)
```

What would be a better/faster way to do this? Is there a straight-forward way to accomplish this asynchronously but respecting the 1-request-per-second threshold? I have read about grequests (no longer maintained?), twisted, asyncio, etc but do not have enough experience to know whether/if one of these is the right way to go.

**EDIT**
Based on Kardaj's reply below, I decided to give async Tornado a try. Here's my current Tornado version (which is heavily based on one of the examples in their docs). It successfully limits concurrency.

The hangup is, how can I do an overall rate-limit of 1 request per second globally across all workers? (Kardaj, the async sleep makes a worker sleep before working, but does not check whether other workers 'wake up' and request at the same time. When I tested it, all workers grab a page and break the rate limit, then go to sleep simultaneously).

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from tornado import httpclient, gen, ioloop, queues

URLS = ["https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat",
        "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=filler",
        "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler",
        "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1"]

concurrency = 2


def handle_request(response):
    if response.code == 200:
        with open("FOO"+'.txt', "wb") as thisfile:#fix filenames to avoid overwrite
            thisfile.write(response.body) 

@gen.coroutine
def request_and_save_url(url):
    try:
        response = yield httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url, handle_request)
        print('fetched {0}'.format(url))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception: {0} {1}'.format(e, url))
        raise gen.Return([])


@gen.coroutine
def main():
    q = queues.Queue()
    tstart = datetime.now()
    fetching, fetched = set(), set()

    @gen.coroutine
    def fetch_url(worker_id):
        current_url = yield q.get()
        try:
            if current_url in fetching:
                return

            #print('fetching {0}'.format(current_url))
            print("Worker {0} starting, elapsed is {1}".format(worker_id, (datetime.now()-tstart).seconds ))
            fetching.add(current_url)
            yield request_and_save_url(current_url)
            fetched.add(current_url)

        finally:
            q.task_done()

    @gen.coroutine
    def worker(worker_id):
        while True:
            yield fetch_url(worker_id)

    # Fill a queue of URL's to scrape
    list = [q.put(url) for url in URLS] # this does not make a list...it just puts all the URLS into the Queue

    # Start workers, then wait for the work Queue to be empty.
    for ii in range(concurrency):
        worker(ii)
    yield q.join(timeout=timedelta(seconds=300))
    assert fetching == fetched
    print('Done in {0} seconds, fetched {1} URLs.'.format(
        datetime.now() - tstart, len(fetched)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig()
    io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.run_sync(main)
```

Comment: Have you considered simply trying it and finding out? I've used [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and found it useful, it's pretty much an async `requests`.

Comment: One very low hanging fruit would be to use a [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) - right now, you're establishing a new TCP connection for every single request. A session will let you keep alive a single TCP connection and reuse it (see [HTTP Persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

Comment: ^^ thanks for the requests.Session tip -- this would definitely be the easiest to do. I will benchmark it against whatever async solution I end up with.

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing the content and then serializing it again. You can just write the content directly to a file.

```
curr_url_request = requests.get(encoded_URL_i, timeout=timeout_secs)
if curr_url_request.ok:
    with open('json_output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(curr_url_request.content)
```

That probably removes most of the processing overhead.

Answer (score 0):

`tornado` has a very powerful asynchronous client. Here's a basic code that may do the trick:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
import tornado

URLS = []
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()


def handle_request(response):
    if response.code == 200:
        with open('json_output.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(response.body)


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def queue_requests():
    results = []
    for url in URLS:
        nxt = tornado.gen.sleep(1)  # 1 request per second
        res = http_client.fetch(url, handle_request)
        results.append(res)
        yield nxt
    yield results  # wait for all requests to finish
    loop.add_callback(loop.stop)
loop.add_callback(queue_requests)
loop.start()
```

This is a straight-forward approach that may lead to too many connections with the remote server. You may have to resolve such problem using a sliding window while queuing the requests.

In case of request timeouts or specific headers required, feel free to read the [doc](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest)

Comment: Thanks! To get this to run, I had to change `loop.add_callback(queue_requests)` to `loop.add_callback(lambda: queue_requests)` so that it doesn't call a Future. Also, the sleep is helpful, but in practice I found that all workers grab a page at the same time, then sleep at the same time, etc...so they don't respect the 1-per-second limit.

Comment: I tested this snipped as it is on `python-2.7` where it works fine, on their website they say that `tornado` is supported by `python-3`, but maybe there's some minor differences.